# Only printing the first line multiple times

Tags: python, printing, readline

A file is passed into the functions and the goal is to print line, however it is only printing the first line multiple times.

```
def printRecord(rec1):
#read reads in a single record from the first logfile, prints it, and exits
    s = Scanner(rec1)
    line = s.readline()
    print(line)
    s.close()
    return line


def printRecords(rec1):
#loops over all records in the first log file, reading in a single record and printing it before reading in the next record
    lines = ""
    s = Scanner(rec1)
    for i in range(0, len(rec1), 1):
        lines += printRecord(rec1)
    return lines
```

Comment: what's the `Scanner` like?

Comment: Just guessing, but you're making a new `Scanner` each time in `printRecord` instead of reusing the one you instantiate in `printRecords`.  I don't know what `Scanner` is so I can't comment further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trouble is that when you close and reopen the log file in the Scanner you start from the beginning of the log file.

Instead, do away with the first function and just read lines in the for loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(rec1), 1):
    line = s.readline()
    print(line)
    lines += line
return lines
```

**EDIT**

By way of being diplomatic, if you wanted to keep both methods, pass the Scanner in as a parameter in the function call and it will keep track of where it is. So instead of creating a new Scanner in printRecord, instead:

```
def printRecord(rec1, s):
```

where s is the Scanner you created in printRecords

Comment: using just one more function would make my life a million times easier but I'm required to use both functions.  I attempted to use the diplomatic version but got the error "printRecord() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: @user3346105 You need to change your calls to **printRecord(rec1, s)** both at the constructor and also in the second function when you call it ie. **lines += printRecord(rec1, s)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `printRecord(rec1)` is simply reading the first line of the file. I may be wrong as I use `open()` instead of `Scanner()`. I don't know if `Scanner` is important, but I would make something like:

```
def printRecords(rec1):
  f = open(rec1,'r')
  lines = f.read()
  return lines
```

Comment: I would love to use a fp but I'm required to use a scanner for this project